# vue 3 input element with different hotkey event modifier depending on os

Tags: vuejs3

New to Vue 3 and I need to use a different v-on / keyboard event modifier, depending on the OS. There is a '$device.isMacOS' variable available elsewhere in the file.

Using '@keydown.meta.k', and it works fine for macOS. Problem is that it needs to be '@keydown.ctrl.k' for OS that isn't mac.

Not seeing a clean, simple solution.

I hope this explanation is adquate. If not, I will gladly clarify.

Any suggestions really appreciated.

**Here's some code:**

```
    <input
      v-if="sidebar.collapsed == false || sidebar.collapsedSwitch == false"
      @focus="onFocus"
      @blur="onFocusLost"
      @keydown.meta.k="onCtrlCmdK" <=== WORKS FOR macOS. NEED keydown.ctrl.k FOR NOT macOS
      ref="input"
      class="w-16 h-5 bg-transparent outline-none"
      :class="{ 'focus:w-5/6': isInputFocused }"
      type="text"
      :placeholder="$t('_global.search')"
    />
```

Need suggestions for how to switch between 'meta' and 'ctrl' events, based on OS. Thanks in advance :)

Thanks
m

Comment: add two separate keydown events for both, then, if needed, check in the methods whether to continue based on the `isMacOS` value

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a good solution:

There is a Vue package called VueUse (https://vueuse.org)

VueUse has a method called useMagicKeys (https://vueuse.org/core/useMagicKeys)

useMagicKeys allows you to listen for however many key events you would like.

The documentation easy to follow and helpful.

Hope this helps.